# js onkeydown equivalent for mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web

I have a web app where an action happens if someone presses the space bar (onkeydown), what would be a nice equivalent for a mobile user (eg android), a tab on screen? How do I capture that?

Comment: you should be able to get a keypress or a keydown event in mobile.

Comment: but what if i want to use the full screen and not have a keyboard on screen?